# cannot retrieve mysqli_affected_rows correctly with in a function

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to delete multiple records with a single function by passing an  array of ids in arguments. My functions is working fine but i am unable to retrieve the correct number of affected rows on success. Although i am having an idea of failure but due to lack of grip in coding i am unable to do it right way. Below is my function

```
 /**
     * Delete a specific customer or customers
     * @param int or array of ids $id
     * return affected rows on success
     */
    public function Delete_Customers($ids){
        foreach ($ids as $id){
        $result = Database::Run("DELETE FROM customer WHERE id=$id");
        }
        return mysqli_affected_rows(Database::$connection);
    }
```

So even when i am deleting multiple records the built in mysqli function is giving my 1 record deleted message.

Thanks

Comment: No need for the loop, just implode the array over , and use WHERE IN: "DELETE FROM customer WHERE id IN ({implode(',',$ids)})"

Comment: what what if user passed only 1 id ?

Comment: Then it would be IN(1). Which is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yup, a set of size 1 is still a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way you've written your code, using a loop to delete one row at a time, the pointer that lets PHP know how many rows were affected is getting reset to 1 each time. I recommend changing your code to not use a loop, and instead just use SQL to handle it all for you

```
public function Delete_Customers($ids){
    $idSetStr = implode(',',$ids);
    $result = Database::Run("DELETE FROM customer WHERE id IN ($idSetStr)");
    return mysqli_affected_rows(Database::$connection);
}
```

Comment: hmm so you made strings of ids

Comment: It's not the string of ID's that's important here, it's the usage of the WHERE IN clause. The string of ID's helps though ;)